# What is the registry location of windows vista search history?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

what is the location of MRU directory in windows vista, when using windows search.

Comment: Sounds like it's for the shell and not for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/clear-file-search-mru-history-windows-7/

Or use this software to manage MRU data

http://www.mrumanager.com/